# How is it possible in Node js to display list of options via console log and ask user to input a option from the displayed list via console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, user-input, console.log

How is it possible in Node js to display list of options via console log and ask user to input a option from the displayed list via console log

> Expected behavior  user@desktop:~$ node test.js
>
> 1. Option 1
> 2. Option 2
> 3. Option 3
>
> Select option to continue: 3 You have selected option 3

Comment: you can use the node standard package [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). There is an example of this right in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a method using inquirer module

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
function main() {
inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
      type: 'list',
      name: 'Options',
      message: 'Select an Item from below list',
      choices: ['alligator', 'crocodile', 'Exit'],
    },
  ])
  .then(answers => {
        if (answers.Options == "Exit"){
                process.exit()
        } else {
                console.info('Answer:', answers.Options);
        }
  });
}
if (require.main === module) {
  main();
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! was looking for the same . Cheers